# How do I get the pageid from a Wikipedia page?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

In a Flask app, or even better just using wikipedia APIs, how can I get the pageid from a Wikipedia url?

I mean from this  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow to  this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=21721040

From the API sandbox I can work it out but only as a search from a title, not from a singular URL.

Said search example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=pageprops&format=json&ppprop=wikibase_item&titles=Stack%20Overflow

Can I query for it in a more straightforward way and without resorting to a wikipedia search? I mean I already know the human readable url...

Comment: In what environment are you working?

Comment: tought it was attainable trough APIs, so forgot to mention it: i'm using Python/Flask, i'm editing the question and tags accordingly

Comment: I was just wondering whether you'd write a JavaScript userscript that runs in that page, in that case you'd just have to access a variable instead of using the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use URLs in the API, you need to use either page names or page ids to identify articles.

Notice that the https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Stack%20Overflow you found is not a "search", it's just exactly the query to get you the page id from the title. Use it.